# How to navigate to another component and pass data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am currently trying to accomplish routing from component to component and pass data so the newly opened component can use this. After some hours of research I stumbled on a few solutions that did not work in my case.

In my application I have two pages: Home and Search. The application consists of a few different layers of components, for example: App.js -> imports Home.js -> imports Body.js. App.js defines the routes by using React Router. The body of the homepage contains a search bar. When a search is executed, the application fetches data and needs to pass this data on to the Search page that will display it. Please see the files below:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Routes,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom";

/* Import Components */
import Home from "./templates/home/Home.js";
import Search from "./templates/search/Search.js";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/" element={<Search/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";

/* Import Components */
import Header from "../header/Header.js";
import Body from "./body/Body.js";
import Footer from "../footer/Footer.js";

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />

                <Body />

                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

**Body**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import './body.css';
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

/* Import Components */
import TitleImage from "./titleImage/TitleImage";
import SearchBar from "./searchBar/SearchBar";
import SampleOccurrence from "./sampleOccurence/SampleOccurence";

/* Import API functions */
import SpecimenSearch from "../../../api/SpecimenSearch.js";

class Body extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchQuery: ''
        }
    }

    updateSearchQuery(query) {
        this.setState({
            searchQuery: query.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSearch() {
        const searchQuery = this.state.searchQuery;

        SpecimenSearch(searchQuery, process.bind(this));

        function process(result) {
            this.setState({
                searchResults: result
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const items = [
            'Frogger', 'Frogger', 'Frogger',
            'Frogger', 'Frogger', 'Frogger',
            'Frogger', 'Frogger', 'Frogger'
        ];

        if (!this.state.searchResults) {
            return (
                <>
                    <TitleImage />
                    <Container fluid>
                        <SearchBar
                            onSearch={() => this.handleSearch()}
                            updateSearchQuery={(query) => this.updateSearchQuery(query)}
                        />

                        <Row>
                            <Col md={{ span: "10", offset: "1" }} className="sampleOccurences">
                                <Row>
                                    <h3 className="sampleOccurencesTitle">
                                        Explore froggies
                                    </h3>
                                </Row>
                                <Row>
                                    {items.map((value, index) => {
                                        return <SampleOccurrence />
                                    })}
                                </Row>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                </>
            );
        } else {
            // console.log(this.state.searchResults);
            // return(
                // <Navigate to="/" state={{data: this.state.searchResults}} />
                // <Search searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
            // );
        }
    }
}

export default Body;
```

As you can see in Body.js, I either tried to navigate the page to Search by using the useNavigate hook and rendering a `<Navigate to='/' />` element ('/' is the set Route of the search page). The hook does not work because hooks are according to React not allowed in React components. The latter works fine when linking to the Search page, but does not manage to pass on data (for example to the props of `<Search />`).

How can I navigate to the `<Search />` page from Body.js and pass data (array of objects) by using React Router?

Comment: `<Navigate to="/" state={{data: this.state.searchResults}} />` that you have commented out is the correct way to pass data via the route transition. What isn't working with this?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I also thought so, but I can not manage to receive the data on the Search page. I assumed it would pass the data as a prop so tried to receive it like: 

`class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log(this.props);
    }
}`

This gives me an empty props object. I can confirm the data in this.state.searchResults is not empty.

Comment: Tom, the passed route state will be accessible from the `location` object, i.e. `location.state.data`. You use the `useLocation` hook to access the `location` object in the receiving component. Do you need help with this part?

Comment: Ok, I used the useLocation hook and it worked!! Many thanks!! I had to rewrite my Search page to a function instead of extended component class of React to be able to use the hook. Do you think it is best practice to always use functions instead of classes or is there some kind of solution that applies to classes being able to use the Location object?

*Edit* I just saw your answer and my additional question was answered in there as well, thanks!

Comment: I've not written a class component in a few years, since React hooks released, but have had to support older class components with Higher Order Components often. Converting older class components to function components is also an option, but entirely up to you if it's worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom, the passed route state will be accessible from the `location` object, i.e. `location.state.data`. You use the `useLocation` hook to access the `location` object in the receiving component.

Sender:

```
<Navigate to="/" state={{ data: this.state.searchResults }} />
```

Receiver:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { state } = useLocation();
const { data } = state || {};
```

If the receiving component is a class component and can't directly use `useLocation` then you can create a custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component to handle this for you and pass `location` down as a prop.

Example:

```
import { useLocation, /* other hooks */ } from 'react-router-dom';

const withRouter = Component => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  // other hooks
  return <Component {...props} {...{ location, /* ...other hooks */ }} />;
};

export default withRouter;
```

Decorate the `Search` component with this `withRouter` HOC.

```
export default withRouter(Search);
```

Now `location` is injected as a prop. Access the route state via `this.props.location.state` similar as above.

Answer (score 2):

For your goal, I wouldn't go with using react-router to pass data. I would consider using a state management library or context.

However, you can accomplish this in two ways:

1. Functional components (with hooks)
   Using `options.state` from [useNavigate()](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate)

Example

```js
// body.js
navigate('/search', { state: {
data: [{id: 1, value: '1'}, {id: 2, value: '2'}]
} });

// search.js
const location = useLocation();
const {data} = location.state; 
// data => [{id: 1, value: '1'}, {id: 2, value: '2'}]
```

2. Class components

Using `options.state` from [<Navigate../>](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/navigate)

Example

```js
// body.js
 <Navigate to="/search" state={{
data: [{id: 1, value: '1'}, {id: 2, value: '2'}]
}} />

...
```